# Symfony 4 formbuilder loop each rows from database table

Tags: arrays, forms, loops, symfony, entity

I have 2 entities :

- Recettes
- Categories

I try to build/list a form based on each rows of the table "Recettes" and display it from a controller.

Any ideas?

=======================

FORM_START

Name1 (TypeText) | Category (ChoiceType)

Name2 (TypeText) | Category (ChoiceType)

Name3 (TypeText) | Category (ChoiceType)

[Submit button]

FORM_END

=======================

Entity RECETTES

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Recettes
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="recettes", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="categorie", columns={"categorie"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Recettes
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var \Categories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $categorie;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategorie(): ?Categories
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    public function setCategorie(?Categories $categorie): self
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Entity CATEGORIES

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Categories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Categories
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `symfony/forms` each Form is an `EventDispatcherInterface`.

You can subscribe to one of the [Events your form fires](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#registering-event-listeners-or-event-subscribers)

In your case you want to add fields before your form is beeing processed.

```
class FriendMessageFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $builder->add('activate_recette_1', ChoiceType::class);
            $builder->add('activate_recette_2', ChoiceType::class);
        });
    }
}
```

You can inject your `RecetteRepository` via Dependency-Injection ans use the results.

Listen to the form events via:

- [Event-Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#event-listeners)
- [Event-Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#event-subscribers)